# HexRays - what is "__OFSUB__()" purpose?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, decompiler, ida

In the following decompiled function using Ida pro's Hex rays:

```
int sub_409650()
{
  int v0; // ecx@1
  int result; // eax@1
  bool v2; // zf@1
  bool v3; // sf@1
  unsigned __int8 v4; // of@1
  unsigned __int16 v5; // cx@2
  unsigned int v6; // ecx@2

  v0 = gS1_dword_62EEA8 & 7;
  result = gS1_dword_62EEA8 - v0;
  v4 = __OFSUB__(gS1_dword_62EEA8 - v0, 16);
  v2 = gS1_dword_62EEA8 - v0 == 16;
  v3 = gS1_dword_62EEA8 - v0 - 16 < 0;
  gS1_dword_62EEA8 -= v0;
  gs2_dword_62EFB4 >>= v0;
  if ( (unsigned __int8)(v3 ^ v4) | v2 )
  {
    v5 = *dword_62EFB0;
    ++dword_62EFB0;
    v6 = (v5 << result) | gs2_dword_62EFB4;
    result += 16;
    gs2_dword_62EFB4 = v6;
    gS1_dword_62EEA8 = result;
  }
  return result;
}
```

It calls `__OFSUB__` but what does this do? I figured it was something to do with overflow - but if that was true then why isn't the condition:

```
// Checking if subtracting v0 is 16 or negative?
if ( v3 | v2 )
```

Update: raw asm is (some stuff renamed now):

```
.text:00409650 sub_409650 proc near      
.text:00409650                 mov     eax, gBitCounter_62EEA8
.text:00409655                 push    esi
.text:00409656                 mov     esi, gFirstAudioFrameDWORD_dword_62EFB4
.text:0040965C                 mov     ecx, eax
.text:0040965E                 and     ecx, 7
.text:00409661                 shr     esi, cl
.text:00409663                 sub     eax, ecx
.text:00409665                 cmp     eax, 10h
.text:00409668                 mov     gBitCounter_62EEA8, eax
.text:0040966D                 mov     gFirstAudioFrameDWORD_dword_62EFB4, esi
.text:00409673                 jg      short loc_4096A5
.text:00409675                 mov     edx, gAudioFrameDataPtr
.text:0040967B                 xor     ecx, ecx
.text:0040967D                 mov     cx, [edx]
.text:00409680                 add     edx, 2
.text:00409683                 mov     esi, ecx
.text:00409685                 mov     ecx, eax
.text:00409687                 shl     esi, cl
.text:00409689                 mov     ecx, gFirstAudioFrameDWORD_dword_62EFB4
.text:0040968F                 mov     gAudioFrameDataPtr, edx
.text:00409695                 or      ecx, esi
.text:00409697                 add     eax, 10h
.text:0040969A                 mov     gFirstAudioFrameDWORD_dword_62EFB4, ecx
.text:004096A0                 mov     gBitCounter_62EEA8, eax
.text:004096A5
.text:004096A5 loc_4096A5:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_409650+23j
.text:004096A5                 pop     esi
.text:004096A6                 retn
.text:004096A6 sub_409650 endp
```

Comment: So then why is code also having v3 = gS1_dword_62EEA8 - v0 - 16 < 0; check which is used in the condition?

Comment: Care to provide the assembly too?

Comment: I've edited in the asm listing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing much to say about it. HexRays did a pretty bad job decompiling this functions to something legible, but it did not make a mistake.

A quick analysis of the given assembly:

```
mov     eax, gBitCounter_62EEA8                 ; eax = gBitCounter_62EEA8
push    esi
mov     esi, gFirstAudioFrameDWORD_dword_62EFB4 ; esi = gFirstAudioFrameDWORD_dword_62EFB4
mov     ecx, eax                                    
and     ecx, 7                              

; esi = gFirstAudioFrameDWORD_dword_62EFB4 >> (gBitCounter_62EEA8 & 7)  
; i.e, esi got shiftted by the 3 LSB's of gBitCounter_62EEA8
shr     esi, cl                                 

; eax = gBitCounter_62EEA8 - (gBitCounter_62EEA8 & 7)
sub     eax, ecx    

cmp     eax, 10h

; gBitCounter_62EEA8 -= gBitCounter_62EEA8 & 7
mov     gBitCounter_62EEA8, eax                 

; gFirstAudioFrameDWORD_dword_62EFB4 >>= gBitCounter_62EEA8 & 7
mov     gFirstAudioFrameDWORD_dword_62EFB4, esi 

; if gBitCounter_62EEA8 > 0x10 { return; }
jg      short loc_4096A5            

; else... continue work
....

loc_4096A5:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_409650+23j
pop     esi
retn
```

A better decompilation would've been:

```
gBitCounter_62EEA8 -= gBitCounter_62EEA8 & 7
gFirstAudioFrameDWORD_dword_62EFB4 >>= gBitCounter_62EEA8 & 7

if (gBitCounter_62EEA8 > 0x10)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    // rest of code
}
```

However, you may notice that HexRays reversed the condition. It has generated this condition:

```
if ( (unsigned __int8)(
    (gBitCounter_62EEA8 - 16 < 0)  ^ 
    (__OFSUB__(gBitCounter_62EEA8 - (gBitCounter_62EEA8 & 7), 16))) // when this is actually the gBitCounter_62EEA8 var before modifications
        | 
        (gBitCounter_62EEA8 == 16) )
```

According to [Intel's reference](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html), `jg` is taken if `ZF = 0 and SF = OF`.

The condition closely represents it:

- Either `Counter == 16` - meaning that `ZF = 0` so the `jg` is not taken
- Either `Counter < 16 XOR __OFSUB__(gBitCounter_62EEA8 - (gBitCounter_62EEA8 & 7), 16)`, which means:

  1. `Counter < 16` (let's call it A) - which means `SF=1`
  2. `__OFSUB__(gBitCounter_62EEA8 - (gBitCounter_62EEA8 & 7), 16)` (let's call is B) which means `OF=1`

  If `A=true` and `B=false` it means `SF=1,OF=0 => SF!=OF`. If `A=false` and `B=true` it means `SF=0,OF=1 = > SF!=OF`, which means that if `A^B` then `SF!=OF`, which means that if `A^B => jg not taken`.

And generally, if the `jg` is not taken, then "rest of code" is to be executed.

I hope that helped your understanding of HexRays behavior. It's decompilation was correct but very redundant (it didn't clear away a lot of garbage that it could) and it couldn't predict the appropriate way to determine the conditions (it took the more "difficult" path)

Comment: But why would it not have just done if (gBitCounter_62EEA8 <= 0x10) instead?

Comment: @paulm I don't know. But it did not make a mistake. It is simply "not smart enough", or was built in this way.